# What does this SQL window function do?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I’m wondering if someone can explain what this portion of code does. I have been trying to lookup in a variety of places but never found a proper explanation.

```
select
    s.*
FROM
    scorecomp s
    WINDOW W as
    (
        PARTITION BY icustay_id
        ORDER BY hr
        ROWS BETWEEN 23 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING
    )
```

For context this is from [here](https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code/blob/master/concepts/pivot/pivoted_sofa.sql). Which creates pivoted (hourly) SOFA and other scores from the MIMIC iii database. From the what I have seen Window functions were used as aggregators. But I have no idea what it does here.

Edit: Upon more reading, now I feel that Window function serves no purpose, I would really like to know if this is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a window "function".  This is a [named window frame definition](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts#def_use_named_window).  In the context of your query, it does nothing, because it is defined but not used.

You could use it with a window function, such as:

```
select count(*) over w,
       . . .
```

The advantage of a named clause is that you can use it for multiple functions without having to worry about errors in the specifications:

```
select count(*) over w,
       avg(x) over w,
       max(x) over w,
```